# Appending two items in one list to a new list in Python

Tags: python, list

I have a list that currently looks like:

```
new_list = ['130 kms', '46 kms', '169 kms', '179 kms', '53 kms', '128 kms', '97 kms', '152 kms', '20 kms', '94 kms', '$266.07', '$174.14', '$187.01', '$488.69', '$401.53', '$106.88', '$398.33', '$493.87', '$205.43', '$248.14']
```

The first element, '130 kms' corresponds with the 11th element ('$266.07') and so on for the rest of the list. I'm trying to convert each of these relationships into a list, and append it to another list 'sort_list' forming a list of lists.

I'm attempting to do this with the code below.

```
**#new_list as written above**
sort_list = []

for l in range(len(new_list)):
    for item in new_list:
        sort_list.append(new_list[item]+[item+10]).split()
```

But it's giving me the error "list indices must be integers, not str". So does this mean that I cannot append strings to a list, or is there some kind of workaround?

This is the output I'm expecting:

```
[[130 kms, $266.07], [46 kms, $174.14], [169 kms, $187.01], [179 kms, $488.69], [53 kms, $401.53], [128 kms, $106.88], [97 kms, $398.33], [152 kms, $493.87], [20 kms, $205.43], [94 kms, $248.14]]
```

Comment: Can you show the exact output you are expecting?

Comment: I am expecting [[130 kms, $266.07], [46 kms, $174.14], [169 kms, $187.01], [179 kms, $488.69], [53 kms, $401.53], [128 kms, $106.88],
[97 kms, $398.33], [152 kms, $493.87], [20 kms, $205.43], [94 kms, $248.14]]

Comment: Edit your question and put that in your question properly formatted please

Comment: I'm guessing you still want your result list entries to be strings, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
new_list = ['130 kms', '46 kms', '169 kms', '179 kms', '53 kms', '128 kms', '97 kms', '152 kms', '20 kms', '94 kms', '$266.07', '$174.14', '$187.01', '$488.69', '$401.53', '$106.88', '$398.33', '$493.87', '$205.43', '$248.14']

new_list1 = []

for x in new_list:
    try:
        new_list1.append([x,new_list[new_list.index(x)+10]])
    except:
        break
for x in new_list1:
    print (x)
```

Output

```
>>> 
['130 kms', '$266.07']
['46 kms', '$174.14']
['169 kms', '$187.01']
['179 kms', '$488.69']
['53 kms', '$401.53']
['128 kms', '$106.88']
['97 kms', '$398.33']
['152 kms', '$493.87']
['20 kms', '$205.43']
['94 kms', '$248.14']
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use list comprehension to create the nested lists. This does the trick:

```
result = []

for i in range(len(new_list)/2):
    result.append([new_list[i],new_list[i+10])
```

Note that if you had a different input string length, you should change the last line to:

```
result.append([new_list[i],new_list[i+len(new_list)/2]])  // instead of +10
```

This produces the following `result` list:

```
[['130 kms', '$266.07'], ['46 kms', '$174.14'], ['169 kms', '$187.01'], ['179 kms', '$488.69'], ['53 kms', '$401.53'], ['128 kms', '$106.88'], ['97 kms', '$398.33'], ['152 kms', '$493.87'], ['20 kms', '$205.43'], ['94 kms', '$248.14']]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is breaking, as explained by the error, because you're looping through a list of strings, and then using that string as the list index, which isn't allowed.

If I understood your objective correctly, you want the result to be a list of lists such as:

```
>> [['130 kms', '$266.07'],['46 kms','$174.14'], ...]
```

If we assume first half of list is distances, and second half is prices, easiest:

```
new_list = ['130 kms', '46 kms', '169 kms', '179 kms', '53 kms', '128 kms', '97 kms', '152 kms', '20 kms', '94 kms', '$266.07', '$174.14', '$187.01', '$488.69', '$401.53', '$106.88', '$398.33', '$493.87', '$205.43', '$248.14']
n_items = len(new_list) / 2
sorted_list = [[new_list[i], new_list[i+n_items]] for i in range(n_items)]
```

More readable:

```
n_items = len(new_list) / 2
distances = new_list[:n_items]
prices = new_list[n_items:]
sorted_list = zip(distances, prices)
```

Note the second option returns a list of tuples instead of a list of lists.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a classic XY problem.   I wonder why you would not back up a bit and collect the data in the form you need for this step.  However, I will post an answer because I think one problem with the existing is that you have to know the number and position of each item in the list.

My solution does not presume that you know where the first data item is, it is similar to @Jeremy Gordon's answer but different.

```
new_list = ['130 kms', '46 kms', '169 kms', '179 kms', '53 kms', '128 kms', '97 kms', '152 kms', '20 kms', '94 kms', '$266.07', '$174.14', '$187.01', '$488.69', '$401.53', '$106.88', '$398.33', '$493.87', '$205.43', '$248.14']

distances = []

for item in new_list:
    if 'kms' in item: # belongs in distances list
        distances.append(item)
        continue
    else:
        first_price = new_list.index[item] # not a distance so first price
        prices = new_list[first_price:]  # starting from the first price grab the rest of the items
        break do not need to iterate further

combined = [[distance,prices[n]] for n, distance in enumerate(distances)]  create the desired list
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is it:
Easy with a list comprehension

NewList1 = [[value, new_list[index]] for (index, value) in enumerate(new_list[:11], 11)]